# Wordpress com php 7+

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, php-7

Atualizei meu servidor para a versão 7 do php, porém não consigo acessar o site. Segue mensagem de erro.

```
A página de site.com.br não está funcionando

site.com.br não consegue atender a esta solicitação no momento.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

O wordpress ainda não tem suporte para php 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O WordPress tem suporte ao PHP7 [desde 2015](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/09/10/wordpress-and-php7/) e lista o PHP7 como [versão recomendada](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) desde o lançamento da versão 4.7.

HTTP 500 é um erro bastante genérico, e não tem relação direta com a versão do PHP. É provável que algum código do seu tema ou plugin esteja errado, causando esse problema.